# Why don't I need to import modules in scripts which are not the main files?

Tags: python, pandas, duckdb

I have a python script and want to query a database with `duckdb`.
Here is my main.py file:

```py
import duckdb
import pandas as pd
import utils.func

con = duckdb.connect(database="db.duckdb", read_only=False)

data = {
    "id": ["1","2","3","4","5","6",],
    "group": ["A","A","A","B","B","B",],
    "names": ["aze","www","ttt","xxxxxx","llllll","ggggggg",],
}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
con.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data AS SELECT * FROM data_df")

my_query="select * from data"

res = utils.func.query(con, my_query)
print(res)
```

As you can see, I have a function to execute my query.
this functions has 2 arguments (the connection to my db and the query)

This function is written in another file named `func.py` and I import it as a module.

Here is func.py:

```py
def query(DB_connection, query):
    print('appel')
    result=DB_connection.execute(query).df()
    return result
```

In `func.py`, I did not import `duckdb`, nor `pandas`. There is only the function.
with the connection the db, I use the method `execute()` from `duckdb` to execute my query.
and then I use the method `df()` from pandas to turn the result into a dataframe.

When I run `main.py`, it works but I am surprised because I thought it should not work because of `func.py` which is not supposed to know how to use the method `execute()` or the method `df()`.

Does it mean I only need to import modules in the main file?

Comment: Each python script only needs to import the **names** that it directly uses. This is the advantage of functions written in other scripts: They can be written to rely *soley* on their parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The `func` module, or more precise the `query()` function doesn't need to know how to use specific methods, it just needs to know how to call methods.  It gets an object `DB_connection` as argument and calls the `execute()` method of that object with an argument `query` which also came as an argument into this function.  What happens then is the responsibility of the `DB_connection` object.  There's no need to know what type that object actually is, as long as it has an `execute()` method that behaves as expected and returns something with a `df()` method.

If a method doesn't exist, you'll get am `AttributeError` for that method.  If a method does exist, but is called with wrong arguments, that method will most likely run into an exception because of that.

There is nothing more a module needs to know about objects given to a function or method defined in that module as arguments.

Here is the disassembled bytecode in Python 3.8 for that function:

```
>>> dis.dis(query)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('appel')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP

  3           8 LOAD_FAST                0 (DB_connection)
             10 LOAD_METHOD              1 (execute)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (query)
             14 CALL_METHOD              1
             16 LOAD_METHOD              2 (df)
             18 CALL_METHOD              0
             20 STORE_FAST               2 (result)

  4          22 LOAD_FAST                2 (result)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

Line 3 is compiled to just calling methods by name.

Answer (score -1):

If I got your question right, then the answer it's yes, the reason because you don't need to import it in your file it's because it's already imported in the main.py

Python it's quite a weird language with a lot of hacks, and basically the interpreter keep the imported libraries available after load in a module.

That said, I will not relay in that behaviour as your code will not be really reusable (will only work if the caller has already imported those libraries) and furthermore, some IDEs will show errors due the missing imports.

So even if works it's better to add the imports into your python file.

Comment: ok thank you.
I noticed somteting weird with my VScode.
Now I imported duckdb and pandas before he function.

When I import modules, vscode will autocomplete the method I'm using.in the main.py file, if i start typing con.exe, vscode will propose to autoccomplete with execute(). 
When I start typing in func.py : DB_connection.exec, i was expecting vscode to propose to autocomplete with exectue() but it does not propose anything.

I think it's because in func.py, DB_connection is not seen as an object from duckdb. How can I do  an object from duckdb?

Comment: I completely disagree with this answer. Of course the code will be reusable. It's even more flexible. `result=DB_connection.execute(query).df()` will work with any `DB_connection` object that has an `ececute` method (and returns something with a `df` method), not just the one you might think of at the moment.